Balena Cloud API - Is there an OpenAPI description available?
When using Balena Cloud API, how can one know what resources or API endpoints are available? I would need a typed HTTP client for accessing Balena Cloud API, but I am unable to find any API specification online or anything like that.
Is there such a thing as an open API specification for the Balena Cloud API?
There is an official SDK built for NodeJS and Python, from the looks of it. But I need it for another language altogether. And the NodeJS one seems to be built "manually", if I am not mistaken.

https://www.postman.com/vipulgupta2048/unofficial-balena/collection/18z1wg2/deprecated-balena-complete-iot-fleet-management-platform

That looks nice, but it says "deprecated", so I imagine that's not up-to-date anymore (while I am sure most things still are present, I imagine not all).

It's a good baseline

@JeremyFiel It does not have any "outputs" defined, meaning once I try to convert that to openapi and auto-generate an HTTP client for something like Java or C#, I won't get any "output contracts / DTOs" which essentially renders the openapi thing obsolete. But it indeed is a nice baseline for who needs, thanks nonetheless. Appreciate it. :)
